# Spring Data JPA LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean getNativeEntityManagerFactory returns null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm trying to attach an Interceptor to my Hibernate JPA EntityManagerFactory following sds's directions on [this post](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/2323-how-to-use-an-hibernate-interceptor-with-spring), but with java config.

Here's the relevant part of my config:

```
@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager txm = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txm.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return txm;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Bean
public SynchronizedEntityChangeInterceptor synchronizedEntityChangeInterceptor() {
    SynchronizedEntityChangeInterceptor synchronizedEntityChangeInterceptor = new SynchronizedEntityChangeInterceptor();
    synchronizedEntityChangeInterceptor.registerEntityClasses(Device.class, Artist.class);
    return synchronizedEntityChangeInterceptor;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceUnitName("metamp-client");
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "false");
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
    return entityManagerFactory;
}

@Bean
public HibernateInterceptor hibernateInterceptor() {
    HibernateInterceptor hibernateInterceptor = new HibernateInterceptor();
    if(entityManagerFactory().getNativeEntityManagerFactory() == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("This shouldn't happen");
    hibernateInterceptor.setSessionFactory(
            ((HibernateEntityManagerFactory)entityManagerFactory()
                    .getNativeEntityManagerFactory()).unwrap(SessionFactory.class));
    hibernateInterceptor.setEntityInterceptor(synchronizedEntityChangeInterceptor());
    return hibernateInterceptor;
}
```

My problem is that "This shouldn't happen" always happens, so `getNativeEntityManagerFactory()` returns `null` although the spring documentation says [otherwise](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.html#getNativeEntityManagerFactory()).

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling `entityManagerFactory()` directly. Try following:

```
@Bean
public HibernateInterceptor hibernateInterceptor(
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory) {
    HibernateInterceptor hibernateInterceptor = new HibernateInterceptor();
    if(factory.getNativeEntityManagerFactory() == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("This shouldn't happen");
    // rest of your code and use factory variable rather than entityManagerFactory()
```